# Kubernetes liveness probe on a secure mTLS health check endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, https, kubernetes-health-check, mtls

I would like some help to solve a particular Kubernetes + mTLS problem please.

How to make Kubernetes liveness probe work on a **secure https mTLS health check endpoint** please?

My application is a web application where a health check endpoint is exposed over a particular port, same port as other business endpoints.

Per security, audit and compliance review, I **must secure all my endpoints over mTLS**, even the simple and innocent health check endpoint.

Per security, audit and compliance review, I **cannot expose any other ports** like doing my business endpoints on https port 1, but health on http port 2.

Hence, this is failing and marking my app as down (since it is over simple http, the endpoint is https)

```
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTP
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10
```

Just to confirm during a test, we disabled https and mTLS, enabling plain old http, everything is working perfectly, but we simply cannot do that.

How to solve this problem please?

Thank you.

Comment: Are you using Istio in your cluster? Did you check https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/security/authentication/authn-policy/#auto-mutual-tls

Comment: Hello Marius, thanks for the comment. Sadly, we are not using Istio, and hopefully I can find a solution without adding too much dependencies.

Comment: I'm afraid kubernetes doesn't support it by default.

Comment: :'(

Thank you Marius for the comment!

Answer (score 3):

You can use script for your Readiness probe.
inside that script you can simple cURL on the end point and also provide required certificate and CA cert.

For example:

```
curl -k https://<url>/health -v –key key.pem –cacert ca.pem –cert client.pem
```

I assume certificate should be stored in secret in the same namespace.
So  you can mount secret having cert in your pod so that your script can use those path to access certificates.

Comment: While this is a solution to use shell script, I was really hoping for a native solution using the HTTP probe it already exists. Also, our base image is a reviewed one and cannot install curl, wget, etc. But Yes, I believe this is a working solution

Comment: can you try changing scheme: http to https ?                                            livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /health
              port: 8080
              scheme: HTTPS
            initialDelaySeconds: 10
            periodSeconds: 10

Answer (score 3):

Can you try changing scheme: HTTP to HTTPS?

livenessProbe:
httpGet:
path: /health
port: 8080
scheme: HTTPS
initialDelaySeconds: 10
periodSeconds: 10

If scheme field is set to HTTPS, the kubelet sends an HTTPS request skipping the certificate verification.

Comment: how should this work on mTLS? 
when I try kube reports `remote error: tls: bad certificate`
`Readiness probe failed: Get "https://10.129.0.216:42001/": remote error: tls: bad certificate` and `Liveness probe failed: Get "https://10.129.0.216:42001/": remote error: tls: bad certificate`

,  curl from Pod: `curl -k 'https://localhost:42001'` get me `curl: (56) OpenSSL SSL_read: error:14094412:SSL routines:ssl3_read_bytes:sslv3 alert bad certificate, errno 0`
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm investigating a solution for the same problem. What I'm planning to do is to have a trusted certificate inside the pod and instead of using http probe, use a command probe and curl my healthcheck endpoint from inside the pod using said certificate.

Answer (score 0):

Mutual TLS (mTLS) aims to warrant the authenticity of both end, this means the probing side (kubelet) must have access to the keys and certificates that it uses to identify itself as well as others at ***runtime***. Kubernetes doesn't have this built-in, a well known solution to this is [here](https://spiffe.io/docs/latest/spire-about/use-cases/). There are many service mesh solutions out there embedded with this solution if you do not want to deploy it directly. Istio, Nginx Service Mesh, AWS App Mesh... just to name a few.

Answer (score 0):

1. Firstly, can you confirm if there are any operations or port 8080 is in use? (Check deployment or pod yaml file and make sure you have referenced it). If nothing is going on over there your health checks would fail
2. Can you remove the "scheme" part set to HTTP? HTTP is the default scheme so it's redundant, unless you want to change it to HTTPS
3. path: /health needs to be valid, make sure it exists on the application.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! 1 - Yes, confirmed, many clients are hitting my service over 8080 (but using httpS) fine. They are getting the business payload response fine. 2 - yes, removed, with or without, health check over mTLS is failing. 3 - Yes, valid, over httpS again, not plan http

Answer (score 0):

similar to https://stackoverflow.com/a/67047770/1747983 answer, here a full YAML example.

I couldn't figure out how to use variables (without going to the env). Would be nice for the PW , port and path.

```yaml
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl -sS -I -k --cert-type P12 --cert /myPath/my-keystore.p12:MyPass123 -f https://localhost:12002/component/info"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command: ["/bin/sh", "-c", "curl -sS -I -k --cert-type P12 --cert /myPath/my-keystore.p12:MyPass123 -f https://localhost:12002/component/info"]
          initialDelaySeconds: 20
          periodSeconds: 5
          timeoutSeconds: 5
```

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to follow above approach then can open one port inside pod which will not be exposed through service. it will be internal to pod and can be used for readiness or liveness purpose.
Microservices follow these approach now a days.

Comment: The second port will be also https. I do not think within one service, one port can be opened over http, one over https

Comment: It can be done. But here i am talking about opening port inside your pod .